# How to jump directly to page N, when `man -a` finds multiple man pages?

Tags: man

Suppose I have multiple versions of a software installed (e.g. `bash`), and that `man -wa` returns mutiple results for that piece of software.

Now, how can I jump directly to the N'th page after executing `man -a`? Currently, I need to close man pages (`q`), until I get to the N'th page.

Also, `man 3 bash` only seems to work for man pages of different sections.

Comment: What Unix are you using? My `man` does not have a `-w` option.

Comment: I'm using macOS.